# Why does Join() need a double transposition of a 1-dim Long array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

**Why does Join() need a double transposition of a 1-dim Long array?**

Due to [MS Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) 
the Join() function requires a sourcearray as "one-dimensional array containing substrings to be joined" *(btw the help site makes no difference whether it is a Variant or Long)*.

*Note: In the [VBE glossary](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#array) 
an array is defined as set of sequentially indexed elements having the same intrinsic data type.*

It's no problem to connect 1-dim Variant arrays via `Join()` and 
it's even possible to join numbers as well as they seem to be internally interpreted as "convert us to strings".

**Issue with a 1-dim array declared as Long**

In some cases I want to restrict the elements type to `Long` and avoid the `Variant` solution mentioned above. - 
Declaring a "flat" array  - here: `Numbers()` - as **Long**, however raises **Error 5** "Invalid procedure call or argument", 
if you try to connect results via a simple

```
'[2] Failing
Join(Numbers, "|") .
```

I found an interesting ► **work around** via a basically redundant **double transposition** (c.f. **`[1]`)**, 
as it "converts" a *flat* 1-dim array eventually back to the same dimension.

```
'[1] work around
Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Numbers)), "|")
```

**Question**

> What's the internal difference how VBA treats both cases and why does `Join()` need a double transposition of a 1-dim Long array here?

---

**Example call to join a "flat" array declared as Long**

In order to show the workaround code line `[1]` as well as the error raising code line `[2]`, 
I integrated a basic error handling showing user defined error lines (`ERL`), too.

*VB Editor's immediate window shows Error 5 in ERL 200:*

```
 OK: [1] 3 elems: ~> 100|200|300
ERL: 200 Error No 5 Invalid procedure call or argument
```

**Example call**

```
Sub JoinArr()
    Dim Numbers() As Long      ' provide for long array Numbers()
    FillNumbers 3, Numbers      ' call sub procedure to assign 3 numbers to array Nums
    ' Numbers is now an array of 3 numbers

    On Error GoTo oops
    '[1] work around - why does Join() need a double transposition in a 1-dim array?
100 Debug.Print " OK: [1] " & UBound(Numbers) & " elems:" & _
                " ~> " & Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Numbers)), "|")

    '[2] join an already existing "flat" array raises Error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" 
200 Debug.Print " OK [2] " & UBound(Numbers) & " elems:" & _
                " ~> " & Join(Numbers, "|")

Exit Sub

oops:     Debug.Print "ERL: " & Erl & " Error No " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

**Sub `FillNumbers` called by above main procedure**

```
Sub FillNumbers(ByVal n As Long, arr)  
    ReDim arr(1 To n)
    arr(1) = 100
    arr(2) = 200
    arr(3) = 300
End Sub
```

Comment: Split() creates a 1d variant array with the first elemen at index 0. Join() is the corollary of Split() and is designed to exactly reverse the process and so needs a variant array.

Comment: ^^^ just for clarity, `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Numbers))` returns a variant array.

Comment: The Excel worksheet function, Transpose() considers a 1d array as a row of values. When you transpose it, it turns it into a 2d array with the values transposed to the first column. Transposing that again turns it into a 2d array with the values in the first row.

Comment: Realize also that Application.Transpose has limits and shortcomings. If you intend to write your array to a worksheet at some point, you are often better served dimensioning and working with 2d arrays from the beginning rather than hoping Application.Transpose can bail you out at write time.

Comment: Thx to hints above. Seems to me that Join() actually expects a Variant (though not evident in MS Help) and the double transposition delivers elements that can be joined. Meanwhile I found that chapter 6.1.2.11.1.16 of the VBA language specification narrows(?) the function declaration as: " Function Join(SourceArray() As Variant, Optional Delimiter As Variant) As String"

Comment: What is your objective, This is kind of a rabbit hole. What do you want to do? Do you want to declare an array as a constant?

Comment: @ExcelHero - my objective is just an explanation to understand why VBA acts this way, as a found a workaround: As I said above: In some cases I want to restrict the elements type to Long :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to `Join()` an array of `Long`s will fail:

```
Sub JoinTestFails()
    Dim Numbers(0 To 2) As Long, msg As String
    Numbers(0) = 0
    Numbers(1) = 1
    Numbers(2) = 2
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        msg = Join(Numbers, "|")
    End With
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

The double use of `TRANSPOSE()` gets around this by generating a one-dimensional, one-based array of `Variant`s:

```
Sub JoinTest()
    Dim Numbers(0 To 2) As Long, msg As String

    Numbers(0) = 0
    Numbers(1) = 1
    Numbers(2) = 2

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Arr = .Transpose(.Transpose(Numbers))
        msg = LBound(Arr) & "**" & UBound(Arr) & vbCrLf
        msg = msg & Join(.Transpose(.Transpose(Numbers)), "|") & vbCrLf & TypeName(Arr)
    End With
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

To me, this use of `TRANSPOSE` is non-intuitive.  I would rather make the `Variant` array with:

```
Public Function MkVar(arr() As Long) As Variant
'   make a variant array from a long array

    Dim temp() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim temp(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        temp(i) = arr(i)
    Next i
    MkVar = temp

End Function
```

and then:

```
Sub JoinTest2()
    Dim Numbers(0 To 2) As Long, msg As String

    Numbers(0) = 0
    Numbers(1) = 1
    Numbers(2) = 2

    arr = MkVar(Numbers)

    msg = LBound(arr) & "**" & UBound(arr) & vbCrLf
    msg = msg & Join(MkVar(Numbers), "|") & vbCrLf & TypeName(arr)

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: *"To me, this use of TRANSPOSE is non-intuitive"* - this is why I asked out of systematic reasons to understand the intransic functioning. Of course I agree that the Variant array offers the easy way (see intro in OP: *"It's no problem to connect 1-dim Variant arrays via Join() "*)

Comment: Not exactly what I hoped to get to fully understand, but accepted as helpful analyze :+)