# How to transpose horizontal array into vertical array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the MsgBox not function when a horizontal array has been converted to a vertical array even though both array's return the same `VarType`?

### Horizontal Array Transposed: [Does Not Work]

```
Dim Horizontal_Array As Variant
Horizontal_Array = Worksheets(sh.name).Range("A1:C1")
Horizontal_Array = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Horizontal_Array)
MsgBox Join(Horizontal_Array, vbCrLf)
```

**Desired Output:** `Key1 Key2 Key3`

### Vertical Array [Works]

```
Dim Vertical_Array As Variant
Vertical_Array = Worksheets(sh.name).Range("A1:A4")
Vertical_Array = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Vertical_Array)
MsgBox Join(Vertical_Array, vbCrLf)
```

**Output:** `Key1 One Four Seven`

| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| Four | Five | Six |
| Seven | Eight | Nine |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A horizontal array needs two Transpose operations:

```vb
Dim Horizontal_Array As Variant
Horizontal_Array = Worksheets(sh.name).Range("A1:C1")

Horizontal_Array = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
         Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Horizontal_Array))
MsgBox Join(Horizontal_Array, vbCrLf)
```

See discussion here: [Why does Join() need a double transposition of a 1-dim Long array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820439/why-does-join-need-a-double-transposition-of-a-1-dim-long-array)